# How to place videos in a grid

Tags: html, css

I want to create a video archive that would look something like [image]
The videos take up 32% of the width each and have a gap of 50. The css code will also be below. My problem is that while I can make one row look like this, when I paste another row below it, it just all goes in the same row and the second group of 3 videos are squished together. I was wondering if there is a way that this can be fixed.

My current code for the videos is:

```html
<div class="videos1">
    <div class="video1">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="video" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <br>
        <div class="caption" style="color:#ffffff">
            Coming Soon!
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="video1">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="video" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe> <br>
        <div class="caption" style="color:#ffffff">
            Coming Soon!
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="video1">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="video" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <br>
        <div class="caption" style="color:#ffffff">
            Coming Soon!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My css code is:

```css
.videos1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  gap: 50;      
}
.video1 {
  width: 32%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Why not just use [`grid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) layout instead of flexbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation

You haven't close `<div class="videos1">`.

### Solution

Add `</div>` at the end of the HTML code you posted and you will be ready to cope paste it as many times as you like.

```
<div class="videos1">
    <div class="video1">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="video" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <br>
      <div class="caption" style="color:#ffffff">
        Coming Soon!
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="video1">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="video" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>     <br>
      <div class="caption" style="color:#ffffff">
        Coming Soon!
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="video1">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="video" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <br>
      <div class="caption" style="color:#ffffff">
        Coming Soon!
      </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- here -->
```

Comment: Even with this, the CSS in his initial example isn't working. I might be wrong, but the closing div was a victim of the StackOverflow code block formatting

Comment: It is right that div must have close tag in HTML 4. but I am pretty curious why you think adding a close tag could make the code automatically do what OP want? Do you think this really answer a question?

Comment: @Lissy93 it it was that then i will back off. But if not by closing it, solves the initial problem that the 'videos' go to the same row (tested it).

Comment: @James by not closing it when he pasted more rows of the same code the `<div class="videos1">` was getting ignored and the other `<div class="video1">` was included in the first `<div class="videos1">`. (small diff between `videos` and `video` on the classes)

Comment: @Lissy93 from the accepted answer seems like it was not a miss typing. But don't get me wrong your [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72020853/14334528) is still preferable if we are talking for code funtionality.

Comment: I doesn't downvote your answer, but I would say even a closing tag is missing, it should not be answered here (should be closed for typo). But anyways, since OP accept your answer , I am OK with that

Comment: I do agree it's overkill and could be answered in a comment but since i saw other solution thought it will be better to throw it here in case it is what needed.

Answer (score 2):

Using CSS [`grid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) layout this should be quite strait forward.

Then use [`nth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) child to target certain rows for the shorter height in your example.

Here's an example from your code. For clarity, I've replaced the videos with just divs, but the concept is exactly the same.

```css
.videos {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
    gap: 0.5rem;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
}
.video {
    min-height: 6rem;
    border: 1px dashed red;
}
.video:nth-child(4n),
.video:nth-child(5n),
.video:nth-child(6n) {
    min-height: 3rem;
    border: 1px dashed orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="videos">
    <div class="video"></div> 
    <div class="video"></div> 
    <div class="video"></div> 
    <div class="video"></div> 
    <div class="video"></div> 
    <div class="video"></div> 
    <div class="video"></div> 
    <div class="video"></div> 
    <div class="video"></div> 
    <div class="video"></div> 
    <div class="video"></div> 
    <div class="video"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I prefer your way but i think you are not answering the question.

Comment: What did I miss? @ioannis-kokkalis

Comment: You did not miss, just feels like you used a tank to kill a fly. Just by closing that div his code could be used as he wanted even if it was not a good solution.

Comment: You didn't miss anything.  The only requirement was for specific layout, which solution provides in a clean way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `flex-wrap: wrap`, moreover `gap: 50` doesnt have unities, you have to especify unities for example `gap: 10px`

**Bonus**

I also recommend using 'calc' when calculating the width, this way you don't have to use 'justify-content', you just have to calculate the space you want minus the 'gap' `width: calc(33.33333% - 10px);`

```
.videos1 {
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.video1 {
    width: calc(33.33333% - 10px);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;   
    background-color:#f1f1f1;
}
```